# Optimal number of moves in "magnetism" puzzle?

Tags: grid-deduction, optimization

Once, I saw a puzzle on **Puzzlopia** (now a Chinese website, just put a .com in the bold text). I call this **"Magnetism"**, where the board and rules are:

> ### Board:
>
> [image: A recreation]
>   <sub>(recreation)</sub>

> ### Rules:
>
> 1) There is an **electron** (denoted by a negative sign) at the most bottom-left, and a **proton** (denoted by a positive sign) at the most top-right.
>   2) They split such that the **electron splits one step north and east,** and the **proton splits one step south and west.** <sub>(diagram above)</sub>
>   3) They can only split if they are **not blocked by the same particle in either direction.**
>   4) When a particle splits and it meets its opposite particle, they are **destroyed.**
>   5) **Destroy every particle to win.**

**What is the optimal number of moves for this board? (which is $8\times8$)**

Comment: Numberphile has a video on this topic. You may want to go and have a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFQGSGsXbXE&t=183s

Comment: @AniketGupta Interesting topic, but I think it doesn't answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [Amorydai](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57236/amorydai) and [u_ndefined](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48462/u-ndefined) who pointed out that I messed up below for the 4x4 and larger grids...

...so the numbers of moves below are all upper limits.

consider a 2x2 board.

> There will be 2 moves. The electron move and the proton moves and all split particles are eliminated

consider a 3x3 board.

> After 2 move of the electron and proton we will have effectively two 2x2 boards with an electron and proton in SE / NW corners - so it will take 2 moves to split the original electron and proton and then twice the number of moves for a 2x2 board. Thus the total moves are$$ 2 + 2\times(moves for~ 2\times2 ~board) = 2+ 2\times2=6 ~moves$$

consider an $n \times n$ board.

> After 2 move of the electron and proton we will have effectively two $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ boards with an electron and proton in SE / NW corners - so it will take 2 moves to split the original electron and proton and then twice the number of moves for an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ board. Thus the total moves are$$ moves for ~ n\times n~board = 2 + 2\times(moves for~ (n-1)\times(n-1) ~board) $$

Thus in for 2x2, 3x3.... up to 8x8 board we have

> 2x2  2 move ; 3x3 6 moves ; 4x4 14 moves ; 5x5 30 moves ; 6x6 62 moves ; 7x7 126 moves ; 8x8 254 moves

and in general

> for nxn we have $$moves for ~n\times n = 2^n - 2$$

Comment: Formula is okay until 4x4, where you can get 12 moves.

Comment: tip: move the electron in a zigzag direction

Comment: @tom If you label the 4x4 board 1 to 4 on first row, 2 to 8 on second, etc. I will put the number of cell where a split needs to happen, obviously electron splits up and right and the proton down and left: 13, 4, 14, 3, 7, 11, 9, 10, 5, 2, 11, 8. This is 12 moves.

Comment: @Amorydai - ok, so many thanks for the explanation... ok so I got it wrong...